# django NameError: global name '' is not defined

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

I have a model that looks like this and I've looked elsewhere already and can't seem to find the right answer. I am using foreignkey constraints but nothing seems to make it work.

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignKey
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
# Create your models here.


class LanguageCode(models.Model):
    short_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    long_display = models.CharField(max_length=75)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{0} -- {1}".format(self.short_code, self.long_display)

class Word(models.Model):
    word_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lang_code = models.ForeignKey(LanguageCode)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{0}".format(self.word_text)

class QuizType(models.Model):
    quiz_type_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.quiz_type_text

class Quiz(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    publish_date = models.DateField()
    quiztype = models.ForeignKey(QuizType)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Quiz #1{0}".format(self.id)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("publish_date", "quiztype")

class Translation(models.Model):
    left_word = models.ForeignKey(Word, related_name='trans_left_word')
    right_word = models.ForeignKey(Word, related_name='trans_right_word')
    quizes = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{0} => {1}".format(self.left_word.word_text, self.right_word.word_text)
```

Then I have a view that looks like this.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from vocabulary.models import  Quiz, QuizType, Translation
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone
from random import randrange


# Create your views here.
class QuizCreate:

    def get_unused_translations(self):
        unused_translations = []
        t_set = Translation
        for t in t_set:
            if not t.quizes.select_related():
                unused_translations.append(t)
        return unused_translations
```

But any call to QuizCreate causes the following error

NameError: global name 'Translation' is not defined

Any ideas are welcome.. and desperately needed

Comment: Is that all the code in the view module?

Comment: Provide a complete traceback please.

Comment: `t_set = Translation` Are you sure about this one?

Comment: `class QuizCreate:` Are you sure about this one?

Answer (score 0):

I think here:

```
t_set = Translation
```

you meant

```
t_set = Translation.objects.all()
```

or something like that.

On the other hand, according to the code you posted, there is no reason for that error. Perhaps you don't have added your app to the `INSTALLED_APPS` variable settings?

Comment: No.. I tried that first as well.. and then thought maybe it was the latter. I also do have it listed in installed apps